# Whats the difference between post_limits and pre_get_posts?

Tags: wp-query, filters, sql

Because of the lack of documentation about [`post_limits`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits), its hard to learn more about this function and when to use it. Never used it before or seen it used so maybe its not to be used?

```
function wpcodex_filter_home_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        return 'LIMIT 0, 25';
    }

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpcodex_filter_home_post_limits', 10, 2 );
```

Based on my testing, post_limits does the same thing as using pre_get_posts

If i wanted to return 5 posts conditionally without paginating the remainder, would i use post_limits or pre_get_posts?

Answer (score 5):

Note that here you're overriding the paging of the main query, with the `posts_limits` filter, by using hardcoded values:

```
'LIMIT 0, 25'
```

where `0` is the offset and `25` is the number of posts to display.

So in this case I would just use `pre_get_posts` with

```
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 25 );
```

and we don't have to worry about the paging.

> If i wanted to return 5 posts conditionally without paginating the
>   remainder, would i use post_limits or pre_get_posts?

If we later decide that pagination is necessary, then we would need to rework your `posts_limits` code. The `pre_get_posts` filter would work as is and we could therefore say that it's at least a more "future proofed" method.

Another thing: If you were using `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()` with *suppressed* filters, then the `posts_limits` filter wouldn't be available while  the `pre_get_posts` hook would be accessible.

Comment: Thanks. There'll still be pagination using 'posts_per_page', 25

Comment: yes the pagination of the main query should hold using the `posts_per_page` in `pre_get_posts`. So it might be a little more convenient to work with the `pre_get_posts` hook rather than "hacking" the generated SQL -  but I don't see it's wrong in any way ;-) PS: If you're using `$query->is_home()` then I don't think you'll need the `is_admin()` check @BradDalton

Answer (score 4):

`pre_get_posts` allows you to alter the query arguments very early on in a request. You can modify anything that would be a valid `WP_Query` argument, including the `LIMIT` via the `posts_per_page` argument. This allows  much, much broader range of effects than `posts_limits` which only allows you to alter one part of the database query SQL.

In your case, use `pre_get_posts` as the Core code will manage pagination for you ( at least if this is the main query(). If you use `post_limits` you will need to track and manage the pagination -- the "0,25" part yourself, incrementing values as you page.